# What does the "Console Check" page do on enforcement.xbox.com?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

On [enforcement.xbox.com](http://enforcement.xbox.com) there is a page called Console Check, but it doesn't have a description. I blindly assumed it was a service that I could use to see if a console was banned on Xbox live.

When I try it out with a serial number that I have access to it merely says that I have to connect that console to the internet / Live in order to see its status using this service. At this point I'm afraid I don't see the point of the service, or that I have somehow misunderstood it. I certainly can't make any checks from a distance if it requires physical access to the hardware.

I understand that it would give no guarantees, but it would've been better than nothing if I had received a report saying "not currently banned" or something.

What is this service used for?

Update: I only read the Swedish FAQ which did not mention Console Check.

Comment: I wonder if that means that that particular console has never been used with Xbox Live. The message is poorly worded, but it could be saying that that console has never been connected to the internet.

Comment: So let me get one thing straight.  If the console is off, this service doesn't work for you? When its powered on and connected to Xbox Live, what does the service do then? I find it odd (as you've said) that is has to be connected to use the service.  I'm wondering if it's like @SaintWacko said, and the console has never been on Xbox Live before.

Comment: Hey, where did that answer go? It quoted a section of the FAQ that wasn't present in the Swedish translation (which I had read through).

Comment: I deleted my answer because I felt it didn't quite answer your question, which is why I think it got 1 downvote as well.  Your question seems to suggest that the console has to be connected to Xbox Live at the time of checking the serial number, which is something you can't really do in the scenario I described in my former answer. (a second hand Ebay purchase of an Xbox 360).   You can find the english faq [here](https://enforcement.xbox.com/en-US/home/howto#sub-topic0-3).  Scroll down to the Can I still be banned if I purchased an Xbox console second-hand section 2nd paragraph for the quote.

Comment: @SaintWacko I think it might mean this as well, but that info would be a bit immaterial even if it were stated explicitly as opposed to just being alluded to. Of course, we could then conclude that the console couldn't possibly be banned, so I suppose it would be kind of useful. Right now I'm left guessing though.

Comment: Assuming of course you can't get your hardware banned through a side channel, like bragging about your modchip in a call to Microsoft support...

Comment: @TimmyJim The English FAQ reference is enough for an accepted answer, I think. It answers my question.

Comment: I'll undelete then if you believe so.  Considering their own FAQ says to use it for when you intend to purchase a second hand console, I would think this service should be available without having to have access to the console first.  Why it doesn't seem to be working, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main purpose of this tool is to check if a console is banned.  This may be handy if you were to attempt to purchase a second hand console.  Their [FAQ page](https://enforcement.xbox.com/en-US/home/howto#sub-topic0-3) states this:

> If you have purchased or intend to purchase a second-hand Xbox 360, you can check its current ban status by entering its serial number into the Console Check Tool. Please note that the current absence of a ban does not preclude the possibility of future enforcement action.

Lets say you were going to buy an Xbox 360 off Ebay.  You have no way of knowing if the console is banned without using this tool.  The seller may tell you that it isn't, but they could be dishonest with you.  If the seller were to provide the serial number (preferably via picture), you could check if the console is banned or not before purchasing it.